# Magento2 reindex via cron job

Tags: magento2, reindex, indexing, command-line, magento-cron

I have a store with 300k products, I set up the reindex to be "Update by Schedule",

But I don't know what is the best way for reindexing, Should I do this manually by SSH command every 24 hours by this command

> **php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

Or I have to set up a cron job to do reindexing.
if i set up the cron job what is he good period.

My concern is, if I set up a cron job each 1 hour, Reindexing takes about 30 minutes to finish, in this case, every one hour I will be blocked for 30 minutes.

Anyone can help me at this point, What I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with version 2.2, Magento creates a crontab for you. they add the Magento crontab to any configured crontab for the Magento file system owner. In other words, if you already set up crontabs for other extensions or applications, we add the Magento crontab to it.

based on this article on Magento website

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

you only need to install the cronjob by this command

**php bin/magento cron:install --force**

The first command in the cron list (magento cron:run) reindexes indexers and your data will always be up to date.

this helped me a lot of understanding indexing via cron job, I hope it will help other people

Comment: is it safe to reindex via cron job? will it have any bad effect on my website data?

Comment: Yes, just be sure to put the indexes to be (re-index by schedule), but this is the best way if you have many administrator working on the same time