# Schedule indexer programmatically

Tags: magento2, reindex, index, indexer

I have a custom index `my_index` that observe the change in a custom table `entity_data`. When changes happen in `entity_data`, my index's `execute` function is called by Magento like this `$indexer->execute([$id1, $id2]);`. I know I can reset the whole index by this command:

```bash
bin/magento indexer:reset my_index
```

And I want to build a similar command for my index which only reset some specific ids, something like:

```bash
bin/magento indexer:reset_custom my_index "id1,id2"
```

So the cron job can run it by schedule.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by cron job. You can set your indexer to run by schedule. Look this once for further clarifications : [Magento2 reindex via cron job](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222260/magento2-reindex-via-cron-job)

Or if you want to do with code this may help  you : [How to set the cron job for indexing in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232250/how-to-set-the-cron-job-for-indexing-in-magento2)

Comment: Yes I am aware of cron job and it is already set up and running. My problem is I want to schedule indexer run for specific ids, like when you edit a product and the indexer will reindex the product id.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CLI command line to handle your requests. [How to add CLI commands](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cli-cmds/cli-howto.html)